# Как правильно: выглянул из-за стены или из под стены?

Tags: орфография, предлоги

Помогите с правильным написанием предлога и объясните почему так

Answer (score 3):

Большой толковый словарь русского языка (под ред. С. А. Кузнецова). Взято из [Грамоты.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0).

> **ИЗ-ЗА, предлог**. *кого-чего*. Указывает на: 1. Предмет, лицо и т. п., с противоположной стороны которых направлено движение, действие. *Из-за угла. Смотреть из-за двери. Выглянуть из-за спины. Самолёт показался из-за горизонта. Мотоцикл появился из-за поворота.*
>
> **ИЗ-ПОД; ИЗ-ПОДО, предлог**. *(кого) чего*. 1. Указывает на направление действия, движения с места, над которым или поверх которого что-л. находится. *Вытащить чемодан из-под кровати. Вылезти из-под стола. Достать платок из-под подушки. Волосы выбились из-под платка. Птица выпорхнула из-под ног. Смотреть, наблюдать из-под ладони, из-под руки.*

***Выглянул из-за стены*** и ***выглянул из-под стены*** — оба варианта возможны, зависит от контекста.

*Он на мгновение выглянул из-за стены и снова скрылся.*

*Кругом была неразбериха. Кто-то выглянул из-под рухнувшей стены.*

*Из-под стены выглянул домовой.*